# Modulo operator in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can we write a basic condition to use modulo operator in Elasticsearch?

like

```
user.created modulo 2 = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you'd want to do this in a script in Elasticsearch. If so, it would be the same as the Groovy modulo operator:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['user.created'].value % 2 == 0",
          "lang": "groovy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Was expecting something on the condition level, as scripting can hurt when querying for 2M users. Do you happen to know if we can obtain the last number and maybe add in a CASE 0,2,4,6,8 for a even conditon? This workaround could be implemented just on the condition level?

Comment: What do you mean by "condition level"?

Comment: I don't think so. The only things possible around these lines are the `ranges` queries/filters...

Comment: Maybe, as another approach that should **definitely** be way faster, is to index the `user.created % 2` at index time in a different field and use a `term` filter for it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the example from Andrei Stefan with Groovy syntax is not working on my instances.

Here's the official "expression" syntax you can use as filter that can maybe work more widely:

```
{
  "script": {
    "script": {
      "source": "(doc['transactionAmount'].value % 2) == value",
      "lang": "expression",
      "params": {
        "value": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```